# How to force user to enter a valid email and not let them click on submit button otherwise?

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit, email-verification, html-formhandler

I am curious how I can force the user to enter a valid email address and if it is not valid don't show the submit button as active?

here's the current code I have. Currently if the email is invalid, it shows a red border but still the user can click on the submit button.

```
$("button[type='submit']").on('click', function () {

        $(".error").hide();
        let hasError = false;

        let emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

        let emailAddressVal = $("#user_email").val();
        if (emailAddressVal == ''){
            $("#user_email").after('<span class="error">Please enter your email address.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        }

        else if(!emailReg.test(emailAddressVal)) {
            $("#user_email").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email address.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        }

        //alert(emailAddressVal);

        if(hasError == true) {
            return false;
        }


    })
```

Here's where the input is entered:

```
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Enter your email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control validate purple-border" id="user_email">

        </div>
```

And here's the submit button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple purple-border">Perform Frame Classification</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a `click` event on the submit button to check the email, check it as the user types (on `keyup` event), and use the result of the test to enable the button (note that we start with the button disabled):

```js
$("#user_email").on('keyup', function() {
  $(".error").hide();
  let hasError = false;

  let emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

  let emailAddressVal = $(this).val();
  if (emailAddressVal == '') {
    $("#user_email").after('<span class="error">Please enter your email address.</span>');
    hasError = true;
  } 
  else if (!emailReg.test(emailAddressVal)) {
    $("#user_email").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email address.</span>');
    hasError = true;
  }

  $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', hasError);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Enter your email</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control validate purple-border" id="user_email">

</div>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple purple-border" disabled="disabled">Perform Frame Classification</button>
```